# How to launch VMWare Server?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware-server

I'm feeling really dumb asking this, but VMWare Server has stumped me.

I've installed VWware Server 2.02 on Windows Vista. I want to install XP in a virtual machine.

All instructions start with 'Launch VMWare and create a new disk image'

I'm completely stumped on what I'm supposed to do to launch VMWare. I don't have a VMWare app in my start menu (I do have 'Manage Virtual Networks' and 'VMWare Server Home Page'. The latter logs me into a local web site with a username/pwd prompt (I don't recall setting a username/pwd upon installation).

Within the app folder I have bunch of exe's...all of which launch a command line script or give me a 'this should not be invoked directly' message.

Bad install or (more likely) am I missing the obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok...

You were just like me and zoomed past all the prompts in setup!

I couldn't work it out at first either but it is quite obvious.

Basically, VMware Server originally came with a client program similar to Workstation, however they have ripped it out and instead now use a web client (which in my view, is rubbish compared to the old client).

navigate to `https://localhost:8333` if locally or `https://<your_IP>:8333` if remote. (I think Https, if it doesn't work, remove the s)

Next, type your **WINDOWS** username and password and it will let you in. The web based control panel basically lets you do everything that you could in the client, just a little slower.

Edit -

Technically you do not "launch" VMware Server, it always runs on your machine... You are just launching the management interface.

Comment: Wow. Yea, it doesn't help that nearly every tutorial out there uses screen shots of a windows app. Thanks for the help! I'm in and I *think* I have a virtual machine built. Now I just need to figure out how to get windows on it... ;o)

Comment: Use your Windows disk or get an ISO with Windows - mount this in the virtual optical drive and install it the same way as you would in a normal computer!

Comment: Well, I think I'm giving up on Virtual Server. I finally got the disk image made and launched it, but I can not get the IE plugin installed to actually interact with it to get windows installed. Seems to be a problem some have. Switching to Virtual box...

Answer (score 5):

Good news -- you **do** have options besides the web interface...

https://yourserver:8333/client/VMware-viclient.exe

That will get you a proper client. No need to do it all via browser. T

Comment: Yes, you can still use the VI client. Better yet, disable the tomcat service and save yourself all that RAM it's eating.

Comment: +1, I had no idea this was included... Wish I did!

Comment: Hmmm, I get a zero-length file when I do this, looks like the file is not actually included in the Server distribution.

Comment: Oh, it definitely is included. In fact, you can dig around the server to find it. Look under the installed tomcat subdirectory if I recall correctly (I no longer run VMware Server.)