# How to start a run a VM in VMWare Server?

Tags: vmware-server

When I had VMWare Player, when I started the program, it would show a list of VMs on my machine that I could open. When I start VMWare Server, I don't see anything like that.

Comment: Waht version are you using?

Comment: The newest one that's free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The management interface is listening on port 8333.  You can access it with a web browser -  (from your VMWare Server machine) https://localhost:8333  or (from a different machine - use the IP Address of your VMWare Server) - https://ip-address:8333

Answer (score 1):

You access it through a web interface from a remote computer.

VMWare Server is [EoA](http://www.vmware.com/support/policies/lifecycle/general/index.html), though and it is scheduled for EoS in less than a year. I would stay away from doing anything on VMWare Server.

Comment: So it virtual machines can't be accessed locally?

Comment: Not from Server 2.0 or ESXi

Answer (score 1):

Seems there *is* an executable client, which you can use instead of the web interface:

[How to launch VMWare Server?](https://superuser.com/questions/76654/how-to-launch-vmware-server/76667#76667)

Comment: Nice, but that's an .exe file. That's made for Winblows.